# Sort by max date per ID, then other records by same ID, then other IDs by their max date

Tags: sql-server

I have data with multiple rows per ID. I would like to first sort by maximum date, but keep the other rows with the same ID together by date descending, then the next group of IDs with the next max date, and so on.

For example, this data

```
create table #tbl (id int, dt date);
insert into #tbl (id, dt)
values (1, '2020-07-01')
     , (1, '2020-07-17')
     , (1, '2020-07-31')
     , (2, '2020-07-07')
     , (2, '2020-07-14')
     , (2, '2020-07-16')
     , (3, '2020-07-02')
     , (3, '2020-07-20')
;
```

would output as

```
id  dt
1   7/31/2020
1   7/17/2020
1   7/1/2020
3   7/20/2020
3   7/2/2020
2   7/16/2020
2   7/14/2020
2   7/7/2020
```

So id 1 has the greatest date, then the other id 1 rows by date descending. Next, id 3 has the greatest date of the remaining rows, then the other id 3 rows by date descending, and so on.

I can get max dates and row numbers but it is sorted by dates then IDs and doesn't keep the IDs grouped together.

Version: `Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Jul 31 2020 08:26:29   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MAX() window function in the ORDER BY clause:

```
select * 
from #tbl
order by max(dt) over (partition by id) desc, 
         id, -- just in case 2 ids have the same max dt
         dt desc
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1b1491b3772fae5a39f8b4e48f3b3120).
Results:

```
> id | dt        
> -: | :---------
>  1 | 2020-07-31
>  1 | 2020-07-17
>  1 | 2020-07-01
>  3 | 2020-07-20
>  3 | 2020-07-02
>  2 | 2020-07-16
>  2 | 2020-07-14
>  2 | 2020-07-07
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most efficient but this seems to give you the output you desire:

```
declare @tempTbl table (id int, dataorder int)
insert into @tempTbl 
select 
    id,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by max(dt) desc)
from
    #tbl
group by id 
order by max(dt) desc



select
    tbl2.id,
    tbl2.dt
from 
    @tempTbl tbl1 left join #tbl tbl2 on tbl1.id = tbl2.id
order by 
    tbl1.dataorder,
    tbl2.dt desc
```